# Stop UIStatusbar interaction

Tags: ios, uiview, uitableview, uistatusbar

I have a UITableView that scrolls to the top when UIStatusBar is touched by the user.

I would like to know how to turn this feature on and off. The reason being is that I have a UIView that pops up in relation to the current selected UITableViewCell, if the user accidently touches the UIStatusbar then the selected UITableVewCell scrolls out of site leaving the information UIView thats loaded on its own with random cells behind it.

So how can I stop the UIScrollView from being unselected  when the info UIView is loaded then selectable when the info UIView is not visible?

Answer (score 1):

This can be controlled by either the `scrollsToTop` property of `UITableView` inherited from `UIScrollView` or the delegate's `scrollViewShouldScrollToTop:` method. This is described best in the
[UIScrollView documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/scrollsToTop).